# como pasar cosas de un array a otro?

Tags: java, array

no logro entender como hacer eso. tengo un array de numeros del 1 al 10 y tengo que pasar a otro array los numeros menores a 5. logro hacer la logica pero no logro como hacer que esos numeros pasen a otro array. no tiene que sobrar espacio en el nuevo array.

```
public class tp8_4 {
    public static void main(String [] args){

        int numeros [] = new int[10];

        numeros[0] = 1;
        numeros[1] = 2;
        numeros[2] = 3;
        numeros[3] = 4;
        numeros[4] = 5;
        numeros[5] = 6;
        numeros[6] = 7;
        numeros[7] = 8;
        numeros[8] = 9;
        numeros[9] = 10;

        for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
            if(numeros[i] < 5){
               System.out.println(numeros[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Y en que momento estás o quieres meter esos números en otro array ??

Comment: como? no te entendi. te paso la consigna mejor Dado un array de enteros, generar otro array únicamente con los elementos menores a 5. 
El array generado debe tener el tamaño exacto de elementos necesario (no deben sobrar posiciones).

Comment: solo se que tengo que pasar los numeros menores a 5 a otro array... pero no tengo ni la mas minima idea de como xd

Answer (score 2):

También podrías usar el método de filter, que te permite justamente filtrar y crear un arreglo nuevo según un criterio de filtrado si la comparación es verdadera, un ejemplo:

```java
import java.util.*;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] arr = { 8, 7, -6, 5, -4 };
    int[] arr2 = Arrays.stream(arr).filter(x -> x < 5).toArray();

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr2)); 
  }
}
```

Esto imprime: `[-6, -4]`;

Answer (score 0):

Pues algo así mismamente

```
public static void main(String [] args){

    int numeros [] = new int[10];
    int contador = 0;

    numeros[0] = 1;
    numeros[1] = 2;
    numeros[2] = 3;
    numeros[3] = 4;
    numeros[4] = 5;
    numeros[5] = 6;
    numeros[6] = 7;
    numeros[7] = 8;
    numeros[8] = 4;
    numeros[9] = 3;

    for(int i = 0; i < numeros.length; i++){
        if(numeros[i] < 5){
           contador++;
           System.out.print(numeros[i] + ", ");
        }
    }
    System.out.println();
    int[] nuevoArray = new int[contador];
    int contadorNuevo = 0;
    for(int j = 0; j < numeros.length; j++){
        if(numeros[j] < 5){
           nuevoArray[contadorNuevo] = numeros[j];
           contadorNuevo++;
        }
    }
    for(int n = 0; n < nuevoArray.length; n++){
       System.out.print(nuevoArray[n] + ", ");
    }
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: muchas gracias!! me estaba volviendo loco

Comment: recuerda marcar la respuesta correcta

Comment: Que pasa si hay un número mayor a 5 en las últimas posiciones?

Comment: Tenías razón @Herrera, no funcionaba, y no había pensado en ello, creo que con la modificación, lo he solucionado.